# How to retrieve login credentials of an instance that was created from a snapshot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-lightsail

**Configuration:**

- AWS Lightsail (Wordpress)

**Background Issue:**

- I lost the SSH key pair of an instance

**Steps Taken:**

- I created a snapshot of the instance
- I created a New instance from the snapshot
- Detached the staticIP from the old instance and attached it to the New instance

**Problem:**

- I can't sign in with the credentials from the old instance
- It doesn't recognise the user name/password I created in the old instance

**Questions:**

1. Are the steps taken an appropriate way to reassign the key pair to an
   instance?
2. When an instance is created from a snapshot, does it mean it is an exact replicate of the old even with the same login credentials?
3. How can I retrieve the user name/password I created in the old instance?
4. How can I assign new credentials to the new instance if the old can't be retrieved?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Lightsail but the standard way to recover access to EC2 instances is to create a new instance, detach the root disk from the old one and attach it as a secondary disk to the new one, replace the ssh key in authorized_keys file, and re-attach it back to the old one. That's what usually works.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to this, if I may ask to learn more, why do we need to reattach it back to the old one and not use the new one?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who happened to be in my situation and looking for an answer:

**Steps Taken to retrieve the login credentials:**

- Login to the SSH console. If you have forgotten the password, the password can be retrieved using `cat bitnami_application_password`
- Retrieve the **Admin-ID** with the following
  `mysql -u root -p bitnami_wordpress -e "SELECT * FROM wp_users;"` Note: The **Admin-ID** is a number, not a username. Remember the number and the email address used with the ID.
- Use `mysql -u root -p bitnami_wordpress -e "UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass=MD5('NEWPASSWORD') WHERE ID='ADMIN-ID';"` Replace **`NEWPASSWORD`** and **`ADMIN-ID`** with your new password and the Admin-ID you noted down earlier.
- Sign in to the wp-admin with the new password and the email address

More info: https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/wordpress/administration/reset-wp-admin-password/